# Check if value exists in MySQL DB in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm creating a game right now that stores quest values into a DB when a player completes his or her quest. The issue I'm having right now is writing a method that searches the MySQL table for the player id and the quest id to check if he or she has **already** completed it.

I'm new to database programming in Java, so this was as far as I got by looking at some sample code elsewhere.

```
public boolean checkQuest(int questid) {
   Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT questid FROM completedQuests WHERE characterid = ?");
   ps.setInt(1, scriptId);
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

}

Basically, I want to check if the quest id exists in the table. If it doesn't, that means the player has yet to complete the quest and thus it is available.

Comment: Do you have a database already setup? Can you already connect to it?

Comment: I do have a database set up and connected to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do this check in the `where` clause and use the Java side to simply check if this query returned any results:

```
Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = 
    con.prepareStatement
    ("SELECT questid FROM completedQuests WHERE characterid = ? AND questid = ?");
ps.setInt (1, characterId);
ps.setInt (2, questId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    // Quest already completed
} else {
    // Quest not completed yet
}

// Close resources etc.
```

Comment: What I originally intended was something of the sort where I pass a questid through a method parameter and check it to see if it exists in the DB. I don't think this does that comparison. My bad for unclarification. Or do I replace the ? with the parameter?

Comment: I fail to understand the question there. What is lacking from this solution?

Comment: If I was to search for a specific quest id, would I substitute the "?"s with the specific questid?

Comment: @Xari no - you would set the `PreparedStatement` with it. That's what `ps.setInt (2, questId);` takes care of.

Comment: @Xari The "?" isn't a placeholder for **you** to replace, it's the way JDBC's syntax allows you to parameterize `PreparedStatement`s.

Comment: Oh, so the ps.setInt(#) is a way for me to insert the value into the parameter listed in order from the con.prepareStatement?

Comment: Thanks so much, that clarifies a lot!

Comment: Also, do I need a try and catch for mysql statements?

Comment: @Xari yes, that would be a good practice. Or even better, use Java 7's try-resource syntax.